# Codeigniter - Can't log back in after changing "cookie_domain"

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

My Codeigniter's sessions used the default value

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
```

But now I need to be able to use CodeIgniter's sessions from domain.com on

- subdomain1.domain.com
- subdomain2.domain.com

So I saw in the codeigniter manual that you can set

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".domain.com";
```

And the extra dot will make all the ci_sessions shared by the domain and subdomains. This works perfect!

However, it is impossible to log back in the system after changing `cookie_domain` from `""` to `".domain.com"` **unless** I manually delete the cookie `ci_session` in the chrome settings.

I can't ask all the users to delete their cookies so I need to find a way. I tried all of this:

```
delete_cookie('ci_session');
setcookie('ci_session', '', time()-3600);
$this->session->sess_destroy();
unset($this->session->userdata);
$this->session->unset_userdata( <array with all the session keys> )
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$cookie)
setcookie($key, '', time() - 9999999);
```

Some useful info maybe, `sess_expiration` is set to 2 weeks, this is why I tried a huge number in the setcookie function:

```
$config['sess_expiration']      = 1209600; // 2 weeks
```

Also, after all these commands to make the cookie expired. Chrome still says that the ci_session cookie expires in 2 weeks. It's as if it was completely oblivious to the function `setcookie`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your current `$config[sess_cookie_name]` from `ci_session` - to something else like `new_cookie`

Then the browser will look for the `new_cookie` name, which wont exist - and thus force a new cookie on all your users

Comment: That would be a good idea, but I'm also using a database table ci_sessions $config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions'; won't all the entries in there be messed up?

Comment: Your table name can be anything you want - leave it as ci_sessions. It doesnt need to match the cookie name.

Comment: I meant the rows in the database, but I just noticed that there is no "ci_session" in any row, so they will just be deleted when they get old I guess?

Comment: yep - it will fix itself - they will just be normal expired sessions over time. The "cookie name" can be anything you want - it has nothing to do with your database or your database records.

Comment: Anyway, it works! I would kiss ya if you were in front of me! I can't believe how fast that answer was, how simple and how solid, no bugs possible, thanks! You answered too quickly though so I can't accept until a few minutes

Comment: Great,thanks for the info! I am a bit curious why the setcookie did not change anything though, you got an idea?

Comment: My theory is that the the domain related cookie config is only used by the browser when the cookie is "created" in the browser, not when it is accessed later. Probably a security related issue to prevent cookie related attacks.